# two dimensional fit with python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I need to fit a function

```
z(u,v) = C u v^p
```

That is, I have a two-dimensional data set, and I have to find two parameters, C and p.  Is there something in numpy or scipy that can do this in a straightforward manner?  I took a look at scipy.optimize.leastsq, but it's not clear to me how I would use it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def f(x,u,v,z_data):
  C = x[0]
  p = x[1]
  modelled_z = C*u*v**p
  diffs = modelled_z - z_data
  return diffs.flatten() # it expects a 1D array out. 
       # it doesn't matter that it's conceptually 2D, provided flatten it consistently

result = scipy.optimize.leastsq(f,[1.0,1.0], # initial guess at starting point
                        args = (u,v,z_data) # alternatively you can do this with closure variables in f if you like
                              )
# result is the best fit point
```

For your specific function you might be able to do it better - for example, for any given value of `p` there is one best value of `C` that can be determined by straightforward linear algebra.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) u,v makes a 2D grid.  I have a data point for each u,v pair.  Don't I need something like np.outer(u,v**p)?  2) I am surprised that "modelled_z" is the third argument in "args".  Don't I need "observed_z" or something like that there?  Thanks.

Comment: With np.outer() it worked fine, so am accepting this as the answer.

Comment: `modelled_z` vs `z_data` was a mistake on my part - I've corrected that. `np.outer` really just depends on how you store `u` and `v`. I'd probably define `u` as `m by 1` and `v` and `1 by n` and it would work as I've written it. I assume you've defined them as 1D arrays, so in that case `np.outer` is good.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the problem into a simple linear least squares problem, and then you don't need `leastsq()` at all.

```
z[i] == C * u[i] * v[i]**p
```

becomes

```
z[i]/u[i] == C * v[i]**p
```

And then

```
log(z[i]/u[i]) == log(C) + p * log(v[i])
```

Change variables and you can solve as a simple linear problem:

```
Z[i] == L + p * V[i]
```

Using `numpy` and assuming you have the data in arrays `z`, `u` and `v`, this is rendered as:

```
Z = log(z/u)
V = log(v)
p, L = np.polyfit(V, Z, 1)
C = exp(L)
```

You probably ought to put a `try:` and `except:` around it in case some of the `u` values are zero or there are negative values.